# PIL saving frames from MPO JPEG at different size and rotation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, jpeg, mpo

I'm trying to split a Multi Picture Object JPEG (from an iPhone depth camera) however when I save the individual frames it saves them out rotated by 90 degrees and the second frame is coming out really small.

Using Python 2.7:

```
from PIL import Image

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True # Without this the second frame can't save

def split_image(image_path)
  image = Image.open(image_path)

  frame_one = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'frame1.jpg')
  image.save(frame_one)

  image.seek(1)

  frame_two = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'frame2')
  image.save(frame_two)
```

These are the images. The first one is the original, the second one is the output of frame 1 and the third is the output of frame 2.

[image]

How can I split these images and have them come out at the right size / rotation?

Bonus question: Is there a way to tell the size of each individual frame?

Comment: I've noticed that iPhones somehow magically rotate images when they _display_ them (all without changing the image itself)—so you may be incorrect about its actual orientation. There may be some way to detect this or figure-out what cause it to occur (but I don't know what that might be).

Comment: Hmmm interestin @martineau. I'll try find more info on that

Comment: There's information described in the Multi-Picture Format file [specification](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-007_E.pdf) (PDF file) about "orientation", so that might prove helpful.

Comment: Looks like using [this tool](http://www.chrisevans3d.com/pub_blog/splitting-mpo-files-with-exiftool-and-python/) the depth data is also rotated 90 degrees and the depth file is much smaller. So I'm thinking Apple didn't think it was necessary to save a high definition depth file (makes sense I guess). The EXIF file it spits out also has a line stating "Orientation:  Rotate 90 cw"

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354867/2836621

Comment: FWIW, a long-time iPhone user I know said there's a way in the device's settings to "lock" this rotating feature (by which I assume he meant ON or OFF).